# SoapUI Free Edition - Can we execute the tests via command prompt and take advantage of test reports?

Tags: soapui

I am trying to run the SoapUI `project.xml` using windows command prompt w/ and w/o options to generate the test report but getting below access denied error. Does test runner execution works for free edition? Or is this related to admin access on your machine?

```
testrunner.bat  C:\Users\meiyer\Desktop\LOAD TOOLS\SOAPUI sample projects\RESTTEST\Locations.xml

testrunner.bat -FPDF -R"JUnit-Style HTML Report"  C:\Users\meiyer\Desktop\LOAD TOOLS\SOAPUI sample projects\RESTTEST\Locations.xml

Configuring log4j from [C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\soapui-     
log4j.xml]
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: global-groovy.log (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:2
56)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.ja
va:220)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurat
or.java:150)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfi
gurator.java:163)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOM
Configurator.java:425)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.ja
va:345)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:827)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
:712)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
:604)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.doOnChange(DOMConfigurator.java:861)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.
java:88)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.<init>(FileWatchdog.java:57)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.<init>(DOMConfigurator.java:853)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurato
  r.java:584)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.initLog(DefaultSoapUICore.java:4
   80)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.init(DefaultSoapUICore.java:124)

    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.<init>(DefaultSoapUICore.java:11
   4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an access rights issue. By default SoapUI tries to write into its SoapUI program directory, which is bad style.

To change this behavior go to `C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\soapui-log4j.xml` and look for the File param values (e.g. in the `GLOBAL_GROOVY_LOG` appender)

Set the value of the `global-groovy.log` to a path your current user has access to. E.g. your user directory.

I tried to use windows environment variables there, but did not have success at that in short term.

Comment: Is there some way to change `${soapui.logroot}`, rather than rewriting it with path in the XML file?

Comment: In case anyone needs this, you can either pass it in to the testrunner.sh 
as -Dsoapui.logout=<directory>, or if you are using the GUI then in the TestRunner window click on Properties and add it as a System Property (no need to include the -D)

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator for SoapUI.exe fixed the issue for me.

Same thing when running cmd in administrator mode